# Undefined function sha256()

Tags: php, cryptography, undefined, trim, sha256

I have this php code:

```
$password = sha256($_POST['password']);
```

but when I run this code it says:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sha256() in .... on line ...ix it as
```

What is wrong with this code and what must I do to fix this as I know that `sha256` exists.

I have also tried:

```
$password = sha256(trim($_POST['password']));
```

But that doesn't work either.

Comment: You may think that `sha256` exists; the fact is, however, that it doesn't. Where is it defined? Why not use `hash('sha256', ...`?

Comment: I am sorry, the title was a slip of the finger :/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use

```
hash( 'sha256', $string );
```

See http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.hash.php

Answer (score 5):

The [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/a_feature_list.html) extension adds the function `sha256()`, and even `sha256_file()`, to the PHP Core.

With the extension installed:

```
<?php
var_dump(function_exists('sha256'));
?>

bool(true)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such function in php standard library. Use `hash` function instead.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php
like :

```
$pass = hash('sha256', $_POST['password']);
```

Answer (score 0):

ehrm. That function [doesn't exist](http://nl.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=sha256&lang=en&scope=404quickref). If you want to use the SHA256 algorithm, use [hash](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) instead.